# How to Make Rendering Fail if Object has no Attribute?

Tags: python, jinja2

If an object `obj` has no attribute `foo`, then I would like referring to `{{obj.foo}}` in a Jinja2 template to fail when rendering.

Currently I'm getting the template text with empty variables. How to get the standard `AttributeError` exception instead?

Sample code looks like this:

```
class Foo:
    pass
  
env = Environment(
        loader=PackageLoader("mydistro"),
        autoescape=select_autoescape()
    )   

t = env.get_template("template/path/to.j2")
print(t.render(obj=Foo()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your environment with [`StrictUndefined`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#jinja2.StrictUndefined) as the `undefined` class.

```
env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader("mydistro"),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(),
    undefined=StrictUndefined,
)
```